# Increase header width and its items

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, grid

I am trying to increase the width size of header text and its contents. I am using the below code and when I try to increase there is no change happening in the page. How can I do that? Am I going wrong anywhere?

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Remedy" HeaderStyle-Width="150" ItemStyle-Width="150">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblRemedy" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Remedy") %>'></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtRemedy" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" Text='<%# Eval("Remedy")%    >' Visible="false"></asp:TextBox>
</ItemTemplate>                                      
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: What control are you using? It's usually the container that needs the width

Answer (score -1):

Maybe specifying a proper measurement unit would help. Try to specify pixels as measurement unit and see what happens...

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Remedy" HeaderStyle-Width="150px" ItemStyle-Width="150px">
```

Comment: Don't think it's the font that needs to be wider, it's the container.